# ASUS UX310UQ compatibility problem?

Tags: nvidia, laptop, asus, 18.04, secure-boot

I've bought this laptop some months ago for school. I'm at 1st year of IT so I'm still a noob, and didn't thought about Linux at all. I'd like to learn to use Ubuntu, but when I've installed 18.04 a few days ago I did get error messages during boot or when turning it off, or sometimes it just freezed all, and could only force it off. 
The only things I did after the installation are: updated the system and installed the nVidia drivers and turned off Secure Boot, installed VLC, Spotify (both from soft. center).
Anyone knows what may be the cause? I would really like to use Ubuntu, but I can't risk my laptop for it, so I'll appreciate any help.
Thanks